# JSON parse error when trying to load my own SQuAD dataset using Huggingface Transformers

Tags: python, json, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to follow [this notebook](https://github.com/huggingface/notebooks/blob/master/examples/question_answering.ipynb) but I get stuck at loading my SQuAD dataset.

```
import transformers
from datasets import load_dataset, load_metric

dataset = load_dataset('json', data_files={'train': 'squad/nl_squad_train_clean.json', 'test': 'squad/nl_squad_train_clean.json'}, field='data')
```

Gives the following error `ArrowInvalid: JSON parse error: Column(/paragraphs/[]/qas/[]/answers/[]) changed from object to array in row 0`.

Does anyone know how to fix this? If needed I can post the complete stack trace.

Comment: Have you validated that your file is standard json?

Comment: Please post a part of the JSON